# Purging sensitive data (password) after use in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, angularjs-scope

I've a form with "apply signature" button, and each time it asks for signature password to pass it to the signature applet.

But in case if user left PC unlocked, and unauthorized person got physical access to browser before session expired, this person can grab password from developer console by watching angular scopes.

Is there any angular-way to prevent it? And what other places behind scope should i check if i want to clean password manually after it was used?

Answer (score 0):

I've used following solution:

handler function in angular scope sets password directly (bypassing angular scope) to a js closure, which acts like value getter. Then when value is retrieved by getter, closure sets value to zero. This solution should guaranty one-time read of password value.

**script**

```
var pwdWrapper = (function() { 
    var pwd = null;
    return {
        set: _.bind(function(val) { 
            pwd = val; 
        }, this),
        get: _.bind(function() { 
            var tmp = pwd; pwd = null; return tmp; 
        }, this)
    }
})();

$scope.setpwd = pwdWrapper.set;
```

**html**

```
<input id="pwd" type="password"/> 
<button ng-click="set($('#pwd').value())"/>
```

Comment: So, now a user that gets physical access to a browser window with an active session can't get the to the password ??? I don't think so ! It's dangerous to provide false sense of security. This is a very sensitive matter.

Comment: @ExpertSystem you are right, this solution is very crude and need improvement.

Comment: I don't think there is any solution for preventing a user with physical access to the PC and active session from finding out the password (and this problem is very tightly coupled with the implementation details: where does the password come from, how is it used from the scripts, where is it sent etc).